# Spaghetti plot in R with different measurement times

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my data set of repeated measures.
score is the dependent variable, exposure is the main fixed factor in my mixed model.

```
structure(list(ID = c(50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 70L, 70L), 
    Time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), Score = c(100L, 
    150L, 100L, 400L, -205L, -601L, 100L, 226L), exposure = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I'd like to do a spaghetti plot to illustrate each participants scores trends over time as the effect of the exposure levels they have.
I want to produce plot that illustrate each participants score trend over time while they group according to their exposure group.
The image I attached is an example of spaghetti plot without the grouping thing

So far this is my code:

```
ggplot ( DB, aes ( x= Time, Y= Score, group_by=exposure, color = ID)+
geom_points()+
geom_line()+
theme_bw()
```

[image: I want something like this, but also divided by exposure levels]

Comment: I'm a bit confused what the question is.

Comment: @teunbrand, Hello, I want to make a spaghetti plot to illustrate each participant score trend over time, grouped by their exposure group. 
My code isn't working correctly, 
I want to produce an Image like what I attached plus the dividing of exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from some spelling mistakes, I think you might want to group by `ID` to make one line per participant, and then colour by `exposure`. If `exposure` doesn't have discrete levels, you might want to leave out the `factor()` bit in the code below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(
  ID = c(50L, 50L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 70L, 70L), 
  Time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
  Score = c(100L, 150L, 100L, 400L, -205L, -601L, 100L, 226L), 
  exposure = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

ggplot(df, aes(Time, Score, group = ID, color = factor(exposure))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>